# The startup disk cannot be partitioned or restored to a single partition. Windows 10 and Mojave iMac Fusion Drive

Tags: bootcamp, disk-utility, windows, partition, fusion-drive

The startup disk cannot be partitioned or restored to a single partition.

The startup disk must be formatted as a single Mac OS Extended (Journaled) volume or already partitioned by Boot Camp Assistant for installing Windows.

I had installed Windows 10 via bootcamp in my mac. Current version is 10.14.2

I received a strange blue screen error and repaired windows. After the repair the boot camp assistant and tools was not installed so its just a copy of windows without boot camp assistance. I would like to erase that volume and try again but boot camp assistant will not erase the drive.

This is the output of diskutil list

[image]

And here is the output of diskutil cs list

[image]

Can anyone please help me, I would follow the advice already provided on this site concerning this issue, but my fusion drive issue is just a little different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very common question. Again, here is the commands you need to enter in a Terminal application window.

The next two commands will remove the unlabeled "Window Recovery" `disk1s4` partition and the "Microsoft Basic Data" `disk1s3` partition labeled `BOOTCAMP`

```
sudo diskutil eraseVolume free none disk1s4
sudo diskutil eraseVolume free none disk1s3
```

The next command return the free space back to the `disk1s2` APFS container partition.

```
sudo diskutil apfs resizeContainer disk1s2 0
```

Comment: followed directions and got this:                                                                    error: nchildren of inode object (id 786499) does not match expected value
Deferred repairs failed
The volume /dev/disk0s2 could not be verified completely
Storage system check exit code is 8
Error: -69716: Storage system verify or repair failed